# After upgrading to geth v 1.18 chain data lost

Tags: ethereum

Last night Mist wallet shower only about 1000 blocks left to sync, this morning it was over 2 million. I closed Mist and ran geth console, and it started downloading from 0 again.
Using Mac.
Does Oct 18 hardfork require redownload of entire ethereum blockchain? Didn't see any reference in documentation.
Thanks

Comment: No it's not required to download the blockchain, but it's a good thing to do as it reduces bloat locally.

Answer (score 0):

No, the fork only requires your client update.

It seems your old version of geth rewinded the chain. What you can do is

1. update your Mist version, geth will be also updated.
   or
2. you can only update geth , start it first and then launch Mist wallet. It will attach to the running geth instance.